# Integrable function with series absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in [-1,1] \\ 0 & x \notin [-1,1] \end{cases}$. Then let $I$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $I(x) = \int_{I} \frac{f(x-y)}{1+y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y$. How do I show that $I(x) \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. The related post is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271390/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-int-infty-infty-cosn2xixdx-converges-a).

Comment: Is $y$ just a constant?

Comment: Did you mean the integral wrt $y$?

Comment: sorry, made a typo, fixed it.

Comment: Hint: Can you upper bound $|f(x - y)|$ for a given $x$ and any $y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I know that $|f(x-y)| \le 1$ but I do not know how to use this..

Answer (score 1):

All the things are nonnegative, so we use Tonelli to proceed:
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{I}(y)\dfrac{f(x-y)}{1+y^{2}}dydx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{I}(y)\dfrac{f(x-y)}{1+y^{2}}dxdy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\chi_{I}(y)}{1+y^{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)dxdy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\chi_{I}(y)}{1+y^{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{|x-y|\leq 1}dxdy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\chi_{I}(y)}{1+y^{2}}v_{n}dy\\
&\leq v_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy\\
&= v_{n}\pi\\
&<\infty,
\end{align*}
where $v_{n}$ is the volume of unit ball, and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy=\tan^{-1}y\bigg|_{y=0}^{y=\infty}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: How do you get that: $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\chi_{I}(y)}{1+y^{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{|x-y|\leq 1}dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\chi_{I}(y)}{1+y^{2}}v_{n}dy$?. Does $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{|x-y|\leq 1}dx = \nu_{n}$?

Comment: The inner integral is just looking for the volume of the ball center at $y$ with radius $1$, but we know that the volume is translation invariant.

Comment: You might wonder it is indeed a closed ball, but closed and open balls with the same radii have the same volumes.

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Comment: $\nu_{n} = 2$ in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't write $n$ because everything is in one-dimensional.

Comment: Why can we switch the order of integration again?

Comment: It is all about the nonnegativity, Tonelli helps.

Comment: What is the statement of Tonelli?

Comment: Look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem).